# cannot stat '/usr/local/lib/odbclib.a': No such file or directory

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/lib/odbclib.a': No such file or directory
configure: error: ODBC header file '/usr/local/incl/sqlext.h' not found!
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure odbc --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am getting this error from the command below:

```
FROM george/php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        freetds-bin \
        freetds-dev \
        freetds-common 

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc  
        
RUN docker-php-ext-configure odbc --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_dblib --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

RUN docker-php-ext-install odbc
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_dblib
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_odbc
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_dblib
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pcntl
```

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/732

I checked this link and I added the line as suggested:

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends unixodbc-dev
```

But it doesn't seem to work. My image is based off Debian.

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Trying to install pdo_odbc, but I am running into difficulties. I am not sure if I need to configure it or not in my understanding not configuring it won't install it, but I am not sure what are the options when configuring it, there's no documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am stuck on this currently

Comment: I only managed to get it working with this wrapper script: https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer